# Provide default value for char in this case

Tags: java

As per the business Requirement , depending upon the input passed , i need to return a appropiate value

For example as shown below

```
public String getValue()
{

if (array.length <2 ) 
{
return ""; 
}

if (array.length == 4) 
{
return "A";
}
if (array.length == 3) 
{
return "B";
}
if (array.length == 2) 
{
return "B";
}

return "Z";

}


char c = new Myclass().getValue().charAt(0);
```

// My question is if the lenght is less than 2 , then it returns null , as a result it is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 Exception

Please let me know , what s the best way to handle this ??

Comment: Your code is ill-formed - what is array? Also, the answer you seek for "best way to handle this?" is something only you know

Comment: Can you modify the type of the return value?

Comment: I have no clue what exactly you're trying to do, but whatever you're doing seems wrong.

Comment: Why do you return a `String` but only expect `char`? You *cannot* read the first character of an empty string, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The "best way to handle" is specific to your needs/context.

Here are some ideas you can try (depending on your need/possibilities):

- Make sure no arrays of length <2 are passed to your function.
- Check the return value against the empty string and do not take `chatAt()` if it is empty
- Return a specific character instead of the empty string

I *guess* you are looking for the second.  In that case you can do something like this:

```
char c = '\0'; // set it to some default value, in case the if's body is not executed.
String val = new MyClass().getValue();
if (val != null && !val.isEmpty()) {
  c = val.charAt(0);
}
```

Note: the code above checks for null and empty string, just to be safe (e.g. handle possible future modifications of `getValue` correctly), as you cannot call `charAt` on neither on a null string, nor on an empty one.

Note: the `""` denotes an empty string.  The null string is `null`.

Note: `isEmpty()` checks whether the string is an empty string.  Do not call if the string is `null` (hence the order of evaluation in the `if`)

Note: as pointed out by others, if the `getValue()` method always returns a string of length 1 in non-error cases and you don't use the return value other than to extract the first character, you can change the return type to `char` and return the charater you are interested in (e.g. `'A'` instead of `"A"`).  This will require you go with option 3 and return a special character (your choice, just make sure it is not one of the "correct" ones returned later) in cases of error (e.g. array of length <2).  This way there is no string created just for one character.

EDIT: fixed code based on comment

Comment: Don't compare strings wih `==`: `val != ""` ==> `!val.isEmpty()`

Comment: Thanks, fixed and added some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in an if statement as follows

```
if(Myclass().getValue() != null && Myclass().getValue().length() > 0) {
     c = new Myclass().getValue().charAt(0);
}
```

You'd probably want define c outside the if statement somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can switch `public String getValue()` return type to `char` (since you are only returning chars anyway) or, if it's not an option, return null character:

```
if (array.length <2 ) 
{
     return "\0"; 
}
```

Provided the way you are using `getValue()`, I would also suggest making it static and pass `array` as parameter:

```
public static char getValue(Object[] array)
```

and use it like:

```
char c = Myclass.getValue(array);
```